# How can I fix appendChild() to create a div element node?

Tags: javascript, createelement

I have written a code which will create a new div element by clicking a button and it is not working.

```js
function addBox1() {
  var btn = document.createElement("div");
  alert('successfull click');
  btn.setAttribute("class", "content");
  document.getElementByClass('auto-grid').appendChild(btn);
}
```

```css
.auto-grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.auto-grid div {
  min-height: 200px;
  border: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<button type='button' class='box1' onclick='addBox1()'>Add box</button>
<div class='auto-grid'>
  <div class='content'> </div>
</div>
```

I got two key points to solve problems from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33838339/javascript-appendchild-not-working).

1. textContent must be inserted - but I am using fixed height and fixed width for class 'content' which I want to create, so I assume adding text content is unnecessary. Still, adding text content doesn't work.
2. addEventListener() also don't work.

I expected, by clicking the button a 'div' element will be added and a box will increase visually. After clicking button, 'div' element is created but appendChild() is not working. appendChild() works only for the following line of code -

```
document.body.appendChild(btn);
```

The code is simple but I am not understanding the problem in it.

[current demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/bmso306t/1/)

Comment: `document.getElementsByClass('auto-grid')[0].appendChild(btn);`

Comment: `document.querySelector('.auto-grid').appendChild(btn);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have more than one element of the same class, then you have an array to iterate through them.

```
var aGrids=document.querySelectorAll('.auto-grid');
    for(var i=0;i<aGrids.length;i++){
    aGrids[i].appendChild(btn);
}
```

This will append to all of them, if you just want to append to one, then find your way to iterate through them until a condition is met.

Answer (score 1):

There is no member function in the [Document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document) interface called `getElementByClass`. It should be [`document.getElementsByClassName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) which returns [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) of found elements not a single element.

Instead you can use [`document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) as bellow or `document.getElementsByClassName('auto-grid')[0]` to get first element from the collection.

```js
function addBox1() {
  var btn = document.createElement("div");
  alert('successfull click');
  btn.setAttribute("class", "content");
  document.querySelector('.auto-grid').appendChild(btn);
}
```

```css
.auto-grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.auto-grid div {
  min-height: 200px;
  border: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<button type='button' class='box1' onclick='addBox1()'>Add box</button>
<div class='auto-grid'>
  <div class='content'> </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The function is called : getElementsByClassName() and returns a list. In your case, you need to get the first element of that list to get your div :

```
document.getElementsByClassName('auto-grid')[0].appendChild(btn);
```